Отправка запроса в мобильное приложение на Python
я хочу отправлять некую информацию в мобильное приложение, как-то это можно сделать

Через firebase https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging?hl=ru
Мобильное приложение должно уметь принимать push сообщения
